# how to access Tableau Public dashboards from Tableau Desktop

Tags: tableau-api

I did some creations in Tableau Public.  I'm using a 14-day trial version until I can buy it in a few days.

How do I access the work I have in my Tableau Public site with the new 14-day trial professional version?

I see now that I want to buy the professional version, but don't see easily how to retrieve my existing work that was done in Tableau Public.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer almost immediately after I posted the question.

Server Menu ==> Tableau Public ==> Open from Tableau Public.